# Return documentation on class constructor method WITHOUT using help or .__doc__

Tags: python, listbox

I'm trying to get comfortable using the Tkinter GUI package for python and I'd like to create a gui function that would return all the methods and attributes docstrings using a `listbox` and button command called `info` per single keyword highlight as displayed below:

[image: tkinter_method display]

I'm trying to get information from the listbox's keyword on the cli per click on `info` using a `get` method request upon retrieval of the curselection, but most of those keywords in the box are string objects, so I CANNOT USE the `.__doc__` method for the Tk() instance object, how can I retrieve the docstring for each method from the directory list of the Tk() instance?

Original Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading, sys


def document():
     """ Define the function's purpose """
     cursor = listbox.curselection()
     item = window_docs[int(cursor[0])]
     print item
    return

 win = Tk()

 Label(win, text="A list of the following packages from Tkinter:\n").pack(side="top")

 scrollbar = Scrollbar(win)
 types = len(dir(win)) #list of the different widgets accessible with Tkinter

 button = Button(win, text="quit?", command=win.quit)

 button.config(bg="#A57706", fg="#042029", relief="ridge", bd=3)

 button.pack(side="top")

 listbox = Listbox(win, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
 listbox.config(height = "400", width="30")

 listbox.document = document  #Bind the function to listbox constructor

 window_docs = {}

 for wid in range(0, types-1):
         constructor = dir(win)[wid] #constructor method
         listbox.insert(wid, constructor)
         window_docs[wid] = constructor.__doc__

 listbox.pack(side='top', fill="y")

 trigger = Button(win, text="info", command=lambda listbox=listbox: listbox.document())

 trigger.place(x=20, y=30, width=30, height=15)
 scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
 scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

 while True:
         win.mainloop()
```

Once again, the info button will generate the documentation of the keyword within the listbox, but I'm unsure how to retrieve the keyword as an **object** to properly get the docstring, any help is appreciated

Comment: Why's this tagged as C#?

Comment: It was autorecommended to me by stack's bot, so I included it

Comment: ^ I'm confused by your comment, what are you suggesting?

Comment: There's absolutely no good reason to call `mainloop` inside of an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah I saw that error and removed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the *`getattr`* builtin function to return an object to an empty variable. So where the defined function *`document`* is for the button command *`info`*, add more logic:

```
 def document():
      """ Define the function's purpose """
      root = Tk()
      cursor = listbox.curselection()
      item = getattr(root, cursor)
      print item
      root.destroy()
      return #exit from function
```

This is the function I was looking for, so I can create a better help menu for tkinter by exporting what the method/attribute on the command line.